# Integrating a recurring payment form with my gateway (wordpress)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, payment-gateway

Here is my code.

I am stuck trying to figure out how to link up to my payment gateway, and tokenize everything. As well as collect all this info..? Any takers any help much appreciated.

My main problem is just connecting to my gateway.

Bascially just given this guide to figure everything out: http://redfinpos.com/wp-content/uploads/RedFin-Developer-Manual-V.2.07.0415-a.pdf
       JUST UPDATED CODE to include ajax

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function startPayment(){
    var paymentData = {
      username : $('#Username').val(),
      password : $('#Password').val(),
      vendor   : $('#Vendor').val(),
      customerID: $('#CustomerID').val(),
      contractID: $('#ContractID').val(),
      billAmt   : $('#BillAmt').val(),
      taxAmt    : $('#TaxAmt').val(),
      totalAmt  : $('#TotalAmt').val(),
      startDate : $('#StartDate').val(),
      billingPeriod:$('#BillingPeriod').val(),
      billingInterval:$('#BillingInterval').val(),
      ccAccountNum:$('#AaAccountNum').val(),
      ccExpDate : $('#CcExpDate').val(),
      ccNameOnCard:$('#CcNameOnCard').val(),
      ccStreet    :$('#CcStreet').val(),
      ccZip       :$('#CcZip').val()

    }

    $.ajax({
      type : "POST",
      url : 'http://www.secure.redfinnet.com/admin/ws/recurring.asmx/AddRecurringCreditCard',
      data: startPayment,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(obj){console.log(obj)}

    })


   // alert(JSON.stringify(paymentData))
  }
</script>

<form>                        
  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" frame="box" bordercolor="#dcdcdc" rules="none" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
  <tbody><tr>
 <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Recurring Payments</td>
 <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc">Recurring Payments</td>
</tr>

                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">Username:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="Username"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">Password:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="Password"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">Vendor:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="Vendor"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CustomerID:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CustomerID"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">ContractID:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="ContractID"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">BillAmt:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="BillAmt"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">TaxAmt:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="TaxAmt"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">TotalAmt:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="TotalAmt"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">StartDate:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="StartDate"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">BillingPeriod:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="BillingPeriod"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">BillingInterval:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="BillingInterval"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CcAccountNum:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CcAccountNum"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CcExpDate:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CcExpDate"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CcNameOnCard:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CcNameOnCard"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CcStreet:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CcStreet"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">CcZip:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" id="CcZip"></td>
                          </tr>
                        
                        <tr>
                          <td></td>
                          <td align="center"> <input type="submit" onClick="startPayment()" value="Submit" class="button"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>
                      

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's a type or not, but you have in your AJAX call:

```
data: startPayment,
```

Is that suppose to be

```
data: paymentData,
```

I would also add an error handler on your AJAX call, so the final call would look like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type : "POST",
  url : 'http://www.secure.redfinnet.com/admin/ws/recurring.asmx/AddRecurringCreditCard',
  data: paymentData,
  dataType: "jsonp",
  success: function(obj){console.log(obj);},
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(errorThrown);
    console.log(jqXHR);
  }
});
```